# Comparing values of one hash to many hashes to get inverse document frequency in ruby

Tags: ruby, hash, word-frequency

I'm trying to find the inverse document frequency for a categorization algorithm and am having trouble getting it the way that my code is structured (with nested hashes), and generally comparing one hash to many hashes.

My training code looks like this so far:

```
def train!
    @data = {}
    @all_books.each do |category, books|
      @data[category] = {
        words: 0,
        books: 0,
        freq: Hash.new(0)
      }
      books.each do |filename, tokens|
        @data[category][:words] += tokens.count
        @data[category][:books] += 1

        tokens.each do |token|
          @data[category][:freq][token] += 1
        end

      end
      @data[category][:freq].map { |k, v| v = (v / @data[category][:freq].values.max) }
    end

  end
```

Basically, I have a hash with 4 categories (subject to change), and for each have word count, book count, and a frequency hash which shows term frequency for the category.  How do I get the frequency of individual words from one category compared against the frequency of the words shown in all categories?  I know how to do the comparison for one set of hash keys against another, but am not sure how to loop through a nested hash to get the frequency of terms against all other terms, if that makes sense.

Edit to include predicted outcome - 
I'd like to return a hash of nested hashes (one for each category) that shows the word as the key, and the number of other categories in which it appears as the value.  i.e. {:category1 = {:word => 3, :other => 2, :third => 1}, :category2 => {:another => 1, ...}} Alternately an array of category names as the value, instead of the number of categories, would also work.

I've tried creating a new hash as follows, but it's turning up empty:

```
def train!
    @data = {}
    @all_words = Hash.new([]) #new hash for all words, default value is empty array

    @all_books.each do |category, books|
      @data[category] = {
        words: 0,
        books: 0,
        freq: Hash.new(0)
      }
      books.each do |filename, tokens|
        @data[category][:words] += tokens.count
        @data[category][:books] += 1

        tokens.each do |token|
          @data[category][:freq][token] += 1
          @all_words[token] << category #should insert category name if the word appears, right?
        end

      end
      @data[category][:freq].map { |k, v| v = (v / @data[category][:freq].values.max) }
    end

  end
```

If someone can help me figure out why the @all_words hash is empty when the code is run, I may be able to get the rest.

Comment: `@data[category][:freq]['word_i_am_interested_in']`?

Comment: An example with expected output would make the question easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks, edited above per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't gone through it all, but you certainly have an error:

```
@all_words[token] << category #should insert category name if the word appears, right?
```

Nope.  `@all_words[token]` will return empty array, but not create a new slot with an empty array, like you're assuming.  So that statement doesn't modify the `@all_words` hash at all.

Try these 2 changes and see if it helps:

```
@all_words = {}                         # ditch the default value
...
(@all_words[token] ||= []) << category  # lazy-init the array, and append
```

Comment: This worked!  Thank you.  To make sure I understand - I wasn't able to push anything into the array because it hadn't been initialized?  i.e. adding the key will return an empty array but the array doesn't exist in time for a value to be pushed in?

Comment: When you have a default value of `[]`, it just returns that for keys it doesn't have.  So all you did was add `category` to an empty array that was returned by the hash, then that array fell out of scope.